# Parse a webpage containing xml but throws an error

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse a xml. Need title, description and pubdate. 
I am getting an error:

```
  for item in doc.findAll('rss/channel/item'):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv, sys
import urllib2
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

toursxml = 'http://www.tradingeconomics.com/rss/news.aspx'
toursurl= urllib2.urlopen(toursxml)
doc= toursurl.read()
#parseString( doc )
#print doc
data = []
cols = set()
for item in doc.findAll('rss/channel/item'):
    d = {}
    for sub in item:
        if hasattr(sub, 'name'):
            d[sub.name] = sub.text
    data.append(d)
    cols = cols.union(d.keys())

cw = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
cw.writerow(cols)
for row in data:
    cw.writerow([row.get(k, 'N/A') for k in cols])
```

Comment: `doc = toursurl.read()` ... toursurl.read() returns a string.

Comment: How can I rectify this?

Comment: Well, first, I think it is NOT recommended to use BeautifulSoup for XML - instead you should be using *BeautifulStoneSoup* : http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing XML

Comment: @Nicarus: I believe BeautifulSoup4 with lxml provides the same functionality as BeautifulStoneSoup. Not that the OP is using `lxml` here.

Comment: @wannaC: You forgot to actually **use** BeautifulSoup. `doc = BeautifulSoup(doc)`. However, BeautifulSoup does **not** support XPath expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse a RSS feed with the wrong tools. Your code is attempting to use BeautifulSoup methods without actually creating a BeautifulSoup object, attempting to use an XPath expression with an API that doesn't support XPath and trying to use a library that is meant for HTML, not XML.

Use [`feedparser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) to handle such feeds instead:

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.tradingeconomics.com/rss/news.aspx')

for item in feed.entries:
    print item.title, item.author
```

This produces:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.tradingeconomics.com/rss/news.aspx')
>>> for item in feed.entries:
...     print item.title, item.author
... 
Latvia Retail Sales MoM Central Statistical Bureau of Latvia
China Foreign Exchange Reserves People's Bank of China
Latvia Retail Sales YoY Central Statistical Bureau of Latvia
Spain Business Confidence Ministry of Industry, Tourism and Trade, Spain
Italy Consumer Price Index (CPI) National Institute of Statistics (ISTAT)
Italy Inflation Rate National Institute of Statistics (ISTAT)
Cyprus Inflation Rate Statistical Service of the Republic of Cyprus
# .... and many more lines
```

Comment: Thanks. How to access pubData?

Comment: @wannaC: You mean `pubDate`? The `.published` attribute gives you access to the textual date, `.published_parsed` to a tuple of integers representing the date and time. See the [common RSS elements](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/common-rss-elements.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to store this in a csv file as well. I tried the same code for writing to csv which I have mentioned above. But there is problem with writing a set to a csv file

Comment: @wannaC: It not clear to me what kind of CSV you are trying to produce. Perhaps make that a new question? Include some sample output of what you expect.